# Convert any Unicode string to int

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, numbers

I have an arbitrary Unicode string that represents a number, such as "2", "٢" (U+0662, ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO) or "Ⅱ" (U+2161, ROMAN NUMERAL TWO). I want to convert that string into an int. I don't care about specific locales (the input might not be in the current locale); if it's a valid number then it should get converted.

I tried `QString.toInt` and `QLocale.toInt`, but they don't seem to get the job done. Example:

```
bool ok;
int n;
QString s = QChar(0x0662); // ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO

n = s.toInt(&ok); // n == 0; ok == false

QLocale anyLocale(QLocale::AnyLanguage, QLocale::AnyScript, QLocale::AnyCountry);
n = anyLocale.toInt(s, &ok); // n == 0; ok == false

QLocale cLocale = QLocale::C;
n = cLocale.toInt(s, &ok); // n == 0; ok == false

QLocale arabicLocale = QLocale::Arabic; // Specific locale. I don't want that.
n = arabicLocale.toInt(s, &ok); // n == 2; ok == true
```

Is there a function I am missing?

I could try all locales:

```
QList<QLocale> allLocales = QLocale::matchingLocales(QLocale::AnyLanguage, QLocale::AnyScript, QLocale::AnyCountry);
for(int i = 0; i < allLocales.size(); i++)
{
    n = allLocales[i].toInt(s, &ok);
    if(ok)
        break;
}
```

But that feels slightly hackish. Also, it does not work for all strings (e.g. Roman numerals, but that's an acceptable limitation). Are there any pitfalls when doing it that way, such as conflicting rules in different locales (cf. Turkish vs. non-Turkish letter case rules)?

Comment: Doing this without knowing the input locale can be dangerous. What happens if the same characters represent different numeral values in different locales? We don't know all the languages and that's why we can't assume none of them have overlapping numeral strings with different meanings.

Comment: Is this hypothetical, or is there an actual example for such a situation?

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense.  If you see an English speaking user enter a character that matches, say, a Chinese digit by accident then do *not* assume he's learned how to speak Chinese and mastered the use of an IME.  Assume he entered wrong data, the 99.9% case.

Comment: There are no cases of this in the Unicode code base.  What can happen (and why I'm not really in favor of using Unicode in C++ program sources) is that two different Unicode characters can have indistiguishable glyphs.  So that if you read the text, you see one character (say a capital Latin A, U+0041), but the actual character is something else (say a capital Greek Alpha, U+0391).

Comment: @HansPassant: It's part of an application that is explicitly about playing around with all kinds of characters. The user should be pleasantly surprised too see that entering foreign numbers works, too.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus 1,000 can mean one thousand in one locale, or one point zero zero zero in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I' not aware of any ready to use package which does this (but
maybe ICU supports it), but it isn't hard to do if you really
want to.  First, you should download the UnicodeData.txt file
from http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt.
This is an easy to parse ASCII file; the exact syntax is 
described in http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-10.html,
but for your purposes, all you need to know is that each line in
the file consists of semi-colon separated fields.  The first
field contains the character code in hex, the third field the
"general category", and if the third field is "Nd" (numeric,
decimal), the seventh field contains the decimal value.

This file can easily be parsed using Python or a number of other
scripting languages, to build a mapping table.  You'll want some
sort of sparse representation, since there are over a million
Unicode characters, of which very few (a couple of hundred) are
decimal digits.  The following Python script will give you a C++
table which can be used to initialize an
`std::map<int, int>`;.  If the character is
in the map, the mapped element is its value.

Whether this is sufficient or not depends on your application.
It has several weaknesses:

- It requires extra logic to recognize when two successive
  digits are in different alphabets.  Presumably a sequence `"1١"`
  should be treated as two numbers (1 and 1), rather than as one
  (11).  (Because all of the sets of decimal digits are in 10
  successive codes, it would be fairly easy, once you know the
  digit, to check whether the preceding digit character was in the
  same set.)
- It ignores non-decimal digits, like ௰ or ൱ (Tamil ten and
  Malayam one hundred).  There aren't that many of them, and they are
  also in the UnicodeData.txt file, so it might be possible to
  find them manually and add them to the table.  I don't know
  myself, however, how they combine with other digits when numbers
  have been composed.
- If you're converting numbers, you might have to worry about
  the direction.  I'm not sure how this is handled (but there is
  documentation at the Unicode site); in general, text will appear
  in its natural order.  In the case of Arabic and related
  languages, when reading in the natural order, the low order
  digits appear first: something like `"١٢"` (literally `"12"`,
  but because the writing is from right to left, the digits will
  appear in the order `"21"`) should be interpreted as 12, and not 21.  Except that I'm not sure whether a change direction mark is
  present or not.  (The exact rules are described in the
  documentation at the Unicode site; in the UnicodeData.txt file,
  the fifth field—index 4—gives this information.  I
  think if it's anything but `"AN"`, you can assume the big-endian
  standard used in Europe, but I'm not sure.)

Just to show how simple this is, here's the Python script to
parse the UnicodeData.txt file for the digit values:

```
print('std::pair<int, int> initUnicodeMap[] = {')
for line in open("UnicodeData.txt"):
    fields = line.split(';')
    if fields[2] == 'Nd':
        print('    {{{:d}, {:d}}},'.format(int(fields[0], 16), int(fields[7])))
print('};')
```

If you're doing any work with Unicode, this files is a gold mine
for generating all sorts of useful tables.

Comment: Actually, arabic-hindic numbers are laid in memory from left-to-right, even if they are in a right-to-left paragraph. That makes the [BiDi](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/) text layout more interesting, but the conversion to numeric is easier.

Comment: My answer already covers this actually (this wheel doesn't need to be reinvented at least in php, java, qt or c#), the problem is that unicode doesn't classify chinese numerals as digits

Comment: I appreciate your diligence, but as Esailija wrote, digit values are already available in Qt. :)

Comment: @rodrigo That's what I wasn't sure of.  How they actually appear in the character stream.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus No real diligence; I've had to solve the problem myself, so I just posted what I did (updated a little---I actually used AWK, and not Python).  Not everyone is using QT, or knows it:-).  If you're using it, by all means use the ready made solution.  Otherwise, the above isn't that difficult, and works in standard C.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the numeric equivalent of an unicode character with the method `QChar::digitValue`:

```
int value = QChar::digitValue((uint)0x0662);
```

It will return `-1` if the character does not have numeric value.

See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qchar.html#digitValue) if you need more help, I don't really know much about c++/qt

---

Chinese numerals mentioned in that wikipedia article belong to `0x4E00-0x9FCC`. There is no  useful metadata about individual characters in this range:

```
4E00;<CJK Ideograph, First>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
9FCC;<CJK Ideograph, Last>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
```

So if you wish to map chinese numerals to integers, you must do that mapping yourself, simple as that.

Here's simple mapping of the symbols in the wikipedia article where a single symbol maps to some single number:

```
0x96f6,0x3007 = 0
0x58f9,0x4e00,0x5f0c = 1
0x8cb3,0x8d30,0x4e8c,0x5f0d,0x5169,0x4e24 = 2
0x53c3,0x53c1,0x4e09,0x5f0e,0x53c3,0x53c2,0x53c4,0x53c1 = 3
0x8086,0x56db,0x4989 = 4
0x4f0d,0x4e94 = 5
0x9678,0x9646,0x516d = 6
0x67d2,0x4e03 = 7
0x634c,0x516b = 8
0x7396,0x4e5d = 9
0x62fe,0x5341,0x4ec0 = 10
0x4f70,0x767e = 100
0x4edf,0x5343 = 1000
0x842c,0x842c,0x4e07 = 10000
0x5104,0x5104,0x4ebf = 100000000

0x5e7a = 1
0x5169,0x4e24 = 2
0x5440 = 10
0x5ff5,0x5eff = 20
0x5345 = 30
0x534c = 40
0x7695 = 200

0x6d1e = 0
0x5e7a = 1
0x4e24 = 2
0x5200 = 4
0x62d0 = 7
0x52fe = 9
```

Comment: Good find, but this will only work for numbers that consist of digits, not number symbols like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus well yes, it only works for those that have been classified as digits in unicode standard